# Perl code crashes after upgrading from rhel6 to rhel8

Tags: perl, rhel

I have been migrating from a rhel6 server with Perl 5.10 to a server with rhel8 and perl 5.24 and 5.26.

Everything works fine except one Perl program crashes executing a warn statement.

Using the built in debugger, I traced the error to the line below. Entering n to step over the subroutine terminated execution.

```
File::Temp::cleanup(/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/File/Temp.pm:934):
934: @{ $dirs_to_unlink{$$} } = ()
DB<44> n
```

The sub function with the warn statement that fails is:

```
sub add_rec_to_db {
    my $info = shift;
    # Returns (errorcode, errormsg). No errorcode means GOOD.

    my $af_rec = Logs::stats_transform($info);
    my $lpd = Logs::db_lpd();
    my $db_file = "$lpd/persistent.db";
    my $dbh = LogsCommon::open_db($db_file);
    my $err = LogsCommon::sql_insert_or_update($dbh, $af_rec, 'all_recs', 'FID');
    if ($err) {
    if ($err =~ /database is locked/) {
        return "DATABASE_IS_LOCKED";
    }
    $err = strip_special_chars($err);
    warn "AddRecToDb: FID=$info->{REC_ID} UNRECOGNIZED_DB_ERROR: $err";
    return "UNRECOGNIZED_DB_ERROR";
    }
    return undef;
}
```

The Perl program executes without error if I change the parameters so it doesn't run this section of code.  DBI and DBD seem to be installed and working correctly.  Even for the sub function that crashes, the code does what it should, until the warn statement.  After executing the warn statement, it should return "UNRECOGNIZED_DB_ERROR".

Using module streams to switch from Perl 5.26 to 5.24 didn't resolve this issue.

Comment: So it crashes in `File/Temp.pm:934`? What happens at that line? How did it reach that line?

Comment: I'm not a strong enough Perl programmer to understand how the programs in the sub directories of /usr/share/perl5 function.  The debugger reached that line by me endlessly stepping into and over subroutines of perl programs, then restarting, until I gave up.  I'm sure if I had stepped into that subroutine instead of over it, the debugger would have kept going.

Comment: It would be interesting to know why `File::Temp` is involved? Can you locate any code creating temporary files or directories? Are you sure the error occurs at the `warn` statement? I would expect it occurred at the closing brace after the `warn`, since that is a location where lexical objects/variables go out of scope (and hence temporary files or directories will be unlinked).

Comment: All I'm sure of is that I got to the warn statement in the debugger, I entered s to step into the next line of execution, then the debugger started going into temp.pm, dbi.pm and path.pm.  The debugger didn't reach the breakpoint at the return statement on the next line.  My perl program does create temporary files .  I'm unsure if temp files were created in this instance, but I'll investigate.

Comment: `File::Temp::cleanup` is called automatically when the process exits. So the problem might be with something triggering the exit and not with `File::Temp`. Try to comment `$err = strip_special_chars($err);` and/or `warn` lines. There might be some magic tied to the `$info`, `$err` variables or to the `warn` handler.

Comment: most likely issue is some module built for a different perl; rebuild all the modules you use with the new perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program exits because of Carp settings:

```
use Carp qw(confess);
$SIG{__DIE__} = \&confess;
$SIG{__WARN__} = \&confess;
```

It did not exit on the Rhel 6 server because the $err variable wasn't raised.  I will post a new question if I cannot determine why the $err was raised on the Rhel8 server, but not the Rhel6 server.